# Remap alt+tab hotkey for a certain app Python

Tags: python, autohotkey, hotkeys

I am trying to create a python programm where it will check if the app i want is open(e.g. Minecraft) and if it is, when the app is in the foreground i want to remap Alt+Tab to press F11 and then minimize the window as like pressing the minimize button of the window. For minimizing i don't want to use the hotkey WindowsKey+M. If there is another way i can achieve that, it's ok with me and i would like to test it, but i would prefer if you could help me with creating the programm. That's the gist of it, if you need a better explanation or anything else i'll try to help you any way i can. Thanks in advance! Also i am using Python 3.7.

EDIT:
I used AutoHotKey in order to achieve the remaping but then alt+tab loses it's original functionality. I would like to prevent that. Here is the script i created:

```
!Tab::
if WinActive("ahk_class Minecraft")
{
    Send, {F11}
    WinMinimize
    Return
}
```

Comment: Personally I would do it with AutoHotKey

Comment: Is it possible for AutoHotKey to press F11 and minimize window? Okay then i will test it and see if i can manage to make it

Comment: Authotkey can definitely press Function keys and minimise windows. I think triggering the macro with Alt +Tab could be challenging to get working in any program, be it Autohokey or Python, as it is a special Windows command. If it is possible at all, then it will definitely be possible in Autohotkey though.

Comment: @PeterWhite I've managed to  remap alt+tab to minimize the app i want, but after that alt+tab loses its original functionality. How can i prevent that? I'll edit my question too so i can add the script i created

Answer (score 1):

Adding `~` as prefix will preserve the hotkey's original functionality.

In the documentation ([Hotkeys | ~](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Tilde)):

> When the hotkey fires, its key's native function will not be blocked
> (hidden from the system)

Change your code to `~!Tab::`

Comment: Great i'll try it out and update my code in whatever conclusion i reach. But if i press alt+tab will it first send the F11 button or the normal functionality of alt+tab will work first?

Comment: I strongly believe it is a race condition. Both will run at the same time (concurrently). Meaning F11 in most occasions will be sent after the native function of alt+tab.